# Django AWS Deploy: After deployment new Database Table was not created

Tags: git, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, django-migrations

I recently made some changes to the `models.py` file that creates a database table on a PostgreSQL database.

Everything works great on the local development system. I pushed the changes to GitHub and then deployed to my test AWS EC2 Linux system. The deployment went without errors and all files reflect what I have on the development system.

The only problem is that the database table was not created after the deployment. If I run `makemigrations` on the test AWS EC2 it just states that there are no changes. What would be the best way to create the new database table that reflects my `models.py`?

For reference this is my deploy script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
git pull
pip install -r requirements.txt
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py collectstatic --no-input
initctl restart gunicorn
```

Comment: I've had this issue.  Had to grant permissions on the table to the db user we were using.  But migrations was acting like it was working.

Comment: @Chris Yes, and they appear in the Test environment. They are in order and contain the changes.

Comment: @KevinHirst I am running a linux AWS EC2 and the database is on RDS. First, this has worked before but how would I go about trying your suggestion?

Comment: Have to somehow grant the access through SQL.  Like "GRANT ALL ON public.table_name to {user}"  - in one case we had to do this on the django_migrations table using the psql tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured due to an old migration file that did not apply correctly. Running `python manage.py showmigrations` is a command that shows which migration files were applied and which were not. For me, there were 8 migration files that did not apply. To fix this, I deleted the last known migration from the django-migrations table in the database. Then I re-ran `python manage.py migrate` and this applied all of the migrations to the current one which then created the database entry. Then, I deployed from my GitHub repository to make sure all changes since the broken migration file were applied. This fixed my problem and hopefully will help the next person who has these type of migration issues.